# Can't set default selection property with ngmodel on Angular 9

Tags: html, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a `select` with a default value on Angular 9. I need two-way-binding, because the value selected must instantly be displayed in an element next to the selection.
I've tried everything, from using Angular Material's implementation of option to normal selection boxes, but I can't seem to set the default selection.

I need to control the selected element with the `isSelected` on `[selection]`, but everything I've tried will display a blank selection box.

The select itself is as follows:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedPrice">
    <option *ngFor="let value of values" [ngValue]="value.propertyName" [selected]="value.isSelected == true"> {{value.str}} </option>
</select>
```

The array is:

```
values = [{ str: 'Varejo 1', propertyName: 'varejo1', isSelected: true, },
    { str: 'Varejo 2', propertyName: 'varejo2', isSelected: false },
    { str: 'Varejo 3', propertyName: 'varejo3', isSelected: false },
    { str: 'Atacado 1', propertyName: 'atacado1',  isSelected: false },
    { str: 'Atacado 2', propertyName: 'atacado2',  isSelected: false },
  ]
```

The component is:

```
export class ProductDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedPrice: number;

  values = [{ str: 'Varejo 1', propertyName: 'varejo1', isSelected: true, },
    { str: 'Varejo 2', propertyName: 'varejo2', isSelected: false },
    { str: 'Varejo 3', propertyName: 'varejo3', isSelected: false },
    { str: 'Atacado 1', propertyName: 'atacado1',  isSelected: false },
    { str: 'Atacado 2', propertyName: 'atacado2',  isSelected: false },
  ];

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MomfortProductsTableComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public product: MomfortProduct) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

I currently get this:

[image]

How would I make it so my `[selected]` condition works?

Comment: You say "I need to control the selected element with the `isSelected` on `[selection]`". Is this a requirement? You can make your life much easier without `isSelected` and without the `[selected]` binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just assign a value to `selectedPrice`:

In your `component.ts`:

```
this.selectedPrice = this.values.find(({ isSelected }) => isSelected ).propertyName;
```

or if you directly want to give it a static value:

```
this.selectedPrice = 'varejo1'
```

**update**

Use `selectedPrice: String`

and the select element can be:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedPrice">
    <option *ngFor="let value of values" [ngValue]="value.propertyName">{{value.str}}</option>
</select>
```

You already have two-way binding because of `[(ngModel)]="selectedPrice"` whenever you want to access the value of the selected option in your `component.ts` just use `this.selectedPrice`.

Comment: selectedPrice is a number, though.

Comment: @MucaP what? but your dropdown values are strings. Why is it a number?

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I forgot to post the class. Am updating the body now in order to clarify the whole question.

Comment: What's stopping you from giving selectedPrice the type String?